# Web service callout failed

Tags: apex

I create a trigger to call an Apex class to call to external web service.
Sometimes I got this message:

> System.CalloutException: Web service callout failed: WebService
>   returned a SOAP Fault: Server was unable to process request. --->
>   Value cannot be null.

Any suggestion?
Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The message 'Value cannot be null', is likely to be a message specific to the external web service your calling. What I would do is enable the Debug Logs or run your code with the Developer Console open to see the logs. When making callouts in Apex the XML transmitted to the external web service is shown. Using this approach, you should be able to identify if the information your passing is different in cases where the callout works and cases where it does not.